# NodeJS in GCloud Error: not find openssl path

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, openssl, google-api-nodejs-client, fastify

I'm working with NodeJS and Fastify in Google Cloud App Engine

I connected to the console of instances with ssh
I executed "which openssl" and the result was "/usr/bin/openssl" so I configured my server.js in this way

```jd
const pem = require('pem');
const jwt = require('fastify-jwt');
const multipart = require('fastify-multipart');
const cors = require('fastify-cors');

const createServer = (options) => {

    const { logSeverity } = options;
    const server = fastify({
        ignoreTrailingSlash: true,
        logger: {
            level: logSeverity
        }
    });
    pem.config({
        pathOpenSSL: '/usr/bin/openssl'
    }); 

    ...

    server.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            server.log.error(err);
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        server.log.info('Server Started');
    });
};
```

the function that Im trying to implement is:

```js
const WebPay = require('webpay-nodejs');;

let wp = new WebPay({
    commerceCode: cert.commerceCode,
    publicKey: cert.publicKey,
    privateKey: cert.privateKey,
    webpayKey: cert.webpayKey,
    verbose: true,
    env: WebPay.ENV.INTEGRACION
  });

  const pay = async (req, res) => {

    let buyOrden = Date.now();
    //transactions[buyOrden] = { amount: amount};
    let url = 'xxxxx';

    await wp.initTransaction({
      buyOrder: buyOrden,
      sessionId: req.body.sessionId,
      returnURL: url + '/verify',
      finalURL: url + '/voucher',
      amount: 10000
    }).then((data) => {
        return res.send(data.url + '?token_ws=' + data.token);
    }).catch(onError(res));
  
  };
```

and the error is:

You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:

> Error: Could not find openssl on your system on this path:
>   /usr/bin/openssl      at
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/pem/lib/openssl.js:237:23      at F
>   (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)      at E
>   (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)      at
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16      at
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5      at
>   /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5      at
>   FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
>
> (node:17) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was
>   handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)

the Dockerfile that I use to make "gcloud app deploy" is:

```html
FROM keymetrics/pm2:10-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json","package-lock.json","/usr/src/app/"]
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
        python \
        make \
        g++ \
    && npm install -g node-gyp \
    && npm install --only=production \
    && apk del .gyp
COPY [".","/usr/src/app/"]
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["pm2-runtime","start","ecosystem.config.js","--env","production"]
```

Comment: has the system user that runs the node server access to that directory?

Comment: ls -la | grep openssl    
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    544944 Oct  9 06:10 openssl

Comment: is your application run by root?

Comment: Im not really sure, I executed "gcloud app deploy" from a folder in my pc, with a Dockerfile that I attach